# How to create SQL custom 4-4-5 Finanical Period date table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to create a SQL script to generate custom financial date table for reporting between years 2010 - 2030. The calendar is loosely based on a 4-4-5 calendar except there are specific rules for periods.

The rules are as follows;

- The fiscal year always starts on the 1 of January
- The fiscal year always ends on the 31 of December
- The last day of each fiscal period (month end) is always on a Saturday
- Fiscal quarters are aligned to the custom periods

See examples below;

**2016 Financial Calendar (Leap Year)**

[image: 2016 Financial Calendar (Leap Year)]

**2017 Financial Calendar**

[image: 2017 Financial Calendar]

I would really appreciate any guidance on creating this table with the usual date dimensions and the custom fiscal values of period and quarter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Especially avoid the impression of listing requirements for a free coding service, which StackOverflow is not.

Comment: Why is `01-Apr-2017` used for the end of `March` rather than `25-Mar-2017`?  Ditto for `01-Jun-2017` versus `24-Jun-2017`?  How far into the next month are we allowed to go / how close to the end of the month must we be?

Comment: Month End is always on the nearest Saturday fitting the 4-4-5 pattern as close as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ignored your `Sales Flash` and `Final Results` flags as there appears to be a degree of custom logic around those that you have not included in your question.  If you wanted to also include US Holidays, you would also need to maintain a separate table of those dates that you could `join` onto to factor into any date calculations done in the table below.

That aside, it appears your biggest issue is calculating the Month End days, as these move around a lot.  This can be done using Windowed Functions and extracting parts of the `Date` values generated in a Tally Table.  I have included a bunch of different `date` functions you could use as examples if you are using this a reference table, which is advised as opposed to creating on the fly.  If you are creating a static table though, you are best just creating it the once and manually collating the lists of special dates to make sure they are correct:

```
declare @StartDate date  = '20100101';
declare @EndDate date    = '20301231';
declare @MonthEndDay int = 7; -- Saturday

-- Tally table creates all the date values which can then be used as your date dimension.
with t(t) as(select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(t))
    ,d(d) as(select top(select datediff(d,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1) dateadd(d,row_number()over(order by (select null))-1,@StartDate)from t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6)
    ,c    as(select d as FullDate
                   ,case when month(d) = 12  -- This logic is to handle the final day of the year.
                       then case when day(d) = 31 then 1 else 0 end
                       else case when sum(case when datepart(weekday,dateadd(d,-1,d)) = @MonthEndDay then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by year(d) order by d) in(4,8,13,17,21,26,30,34,39,43,47,52)
                                   and datepart(weekday,d) = @MonthEndDay
                               then 1
                               else 0
                               end
                       end as FiscalPeriodEndDate
                   ,sum(case when datepart(weekday,dateadd(d,-1,d)) = @MonthEndDay then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by year(d) order by d) as WeekNum
                   ,((sum(case when datepart(weekday,dateadd(d,-1,d)) = @MonthEndDay then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by year(d) order by d)-1) / 13)+1 as QuarterNum
             from d
            )
select FullDate
      ,FiscalPeriodEndDate
      ,WeekNum

         -- Where there is a 53rd week it will show as the 5th Quarter per the calculation above, so change it to 4th.
      ,case when QuarterNum > 4 then 4 else QuarterNum end as QuarterNum

         -- Examples of different date functions you can use to make querying and reporting easier and when indexed properly, a lot faster.
      ,year(FullDate) as DateYear
      ,month(FullDate) as DateMonth
      ,day(FullDate) as DateDay
      ,datepart(weekday,FullDate) as DateWeekDayNum
      ,datename(weekday,FullDate) as DateWeekDayName
from c
order by FullDate;
```

Output - Note the `FiscalPeriodEndDate` flag for your financial periods:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
|  FullDate  | FiscalPeriodEndDate | WeekNum | QuarterNum | DateYear | DateMonth | DateDay | DateWeekDayNum | DateWeekDayName |
+------------+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| ...etc     |                     |         |            |          |           |         |                |                 |
| 2016-01-28 |                   0 |       4 |          1 |     2016 |         1 |      28 |              5 | Thursday        |
| 2016-01-29 |                   0 |       4 |          1 |     2016 |         1 |      29 |              6 | Friday          |
| 2016-01-30 |                   1 |       4 |          1 |     2016 |         1 |      30 |              7 | Saturday        |
| 2016-01-31 |                   0 |       5 |          1 |     2016 |         1 |      31 |              1 | Sunday          |
| 2016-02-01 |                   0 |       5 |          1 |     2016 |         2 |       1 |              2 | Monday          |
| ...etc     |                     |         |            |          |           |         |                |                 |
| 2016-02-25 |                   0 |       8 |          1 |     2016 |         2 |      25 |              5 | Thursday        |
| 2016-02-26 |                   0 |       8 |          1 |     2016 |         2 |      26 |              6 | Friday          |
| 2016-02-27 |                   1 |       8 |          1 |     2016 |         2 |      27 |              7 | Saturday        |
| 2016-02-28 |                   0 |       9 |          1 |     2016 |         2 |      28 |              1 | Sunday          |
| 2016-02-29 |                   0 |       9 |          1 |     2016 |         2 |      29 |              2 | Monday          |
| ...etc     |                     |         |            |          |           |         |                |                 |
+------------+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: iamdave, thank you very much for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: I'll post back any changes for the broader community. Thanks Again!

Comment: I tried adding the below to identify the 12 periods in the year, but it didn't line up. Is it possible to identify each period by the FiscalPeriodEndDate?

Comment: ,(sum(case when datepart(weekday,dateadd(d,-1,d)) = @MonthEndDay then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by year(d) order by d) /3)+1 as FiscalPeriod

Comment: @Nick  What do you mean by *Identify the 12 periods*?  Simply number them?

Comment: @Nick  If you just want to number the Fiscal Periods in the year, add this to the final query: `sum(FiscalPeriodEndDate) over (partition by year(FullDate) order by FullDate) + 1 - FiscalPeriodEndDate as FiscalPeriodNumber`

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was trying to achieve. Thanks iamdave!!